# MySQL Optimizing LEFT Join for Large Data Query with Same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table SQL here

```
| id | dataid |  datarow | datacolumn | datavalue
_________________________________________________
|  1  |  1     |     1    | FirstName   |  John
|  1  |  1     |     1    | LastName    |  Lobo
|  1  |  1     |     1    | Age         |  35
|  1  |  1     |     2    | FirstName   |  Mich
|  1  |  1     |     2    | LastName    |  Handness
|  1  |  1     |     2    | Age         |  22
|  1  |  1     |     3    | FirstName   |  Mike
|  1  |  1     |     3    | LastName    |  Longbow
|  1  |  1     |     3    | Age         |  55
```

Which will output something like this

```
FirstName  LastName Age
   John      Lobo   35
   Mich      Handness 22
   Mike      Longbow  55
SELECT DISTINCT     
        t1.datavalue AS Firstname, 
        t2.datavalue AS Lastname,
        t3.datavalue AS Age

FROM largedatatable t1 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT datavalue,datarow FROM largedatatable WHERE           datacolumn='LastName') t2 ON t1.datarow = t2.datarow
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT datavalue,datarow FROM largedatatable WHERE datacolumn='Age') t3 ON t1.datarow = t3.datarow

WHERE t1.dataid = 1
```

Which gives me result like

```
Firstname  LastName   Age
John        Lobo      35
Mich      Handness    22
Mike      Longbow     55
```

Now the script works perfectly fine; But the query is slow if its a large data set. Is there anyway I could still optimize this SQL Query. Thanks!

Comment: Use a group by with an if statement it would do the query just once

Comment: First of all, your table structure itself looks like it could be slowing you down. Beyond this do you have indexes in all the useful places (for example on column you are joining on?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would solve your problem or, at least, it will run faster because it will fetch the table just once:

```
select 
    max(case datacolumn when 'FirstName' then datavalue else '' end) as FirstName,
    max(case datacolumn when 'LastName' then datavalue else '' end) as LastName,
    max(case datacolumn when 'Age' then datavalue else '' end) as Age
from 
    large
group by datarow
```

See it here at fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4045/11

Comment: NAILED IT! 0.32 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure you have an index on (  datarow, datacolumn ) to help your join, but your join could be simplified to

```
SELECT 
        t1.datavalue AS Firstname, 
        t2.datavalue AS Lastname,
        t3.datavalue AS Age
   FROM 
      largedatatable t1
         LEFT JOIN largedatatable t2
            on t1.datarow = t2.datarow
           and t2.datacolumn = 'LastName'
         LEFT JOIN largedatatable t3
            on t1.datarow = t3.datarow
           and t3.datacolumn = 'Age'
   WHERE
      t1.datacolumn = 'FirstName'
```

This will only go through your primary table once based on only the first name column but pull the columns from second instances without requiring the MAX() or GROUP BY of aggregates.